# Error getting benchmark list: Other: Exported method Benchmark_benchmark_metadata is not found

Tags: benchmarking

While trying to run benchmark with the following command, I am getting errors:

```
target/debug/imbue-collator benchmark --chain=pukimak.json --steps=100 --repeat=200 --pallet=proposals --extrinsic=* --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --heap-pages=4096 --output=example_weights.rs --template=./scripts/frame-weight-template.hbs
```

Error:

```
Error: Input("Error getting benchmark list: Other: Exported method Benchmark_benchmark_metadata is not found")
```

Used local chain spec via this command:

```
./target/debug/imbue-collator build-spec --chain imbue-dev --raw --disable-default-bootnode > pukimak.json
```

Update:
Able to run benchmark help command using the collator on CLI:

````
imbue-collator 2.0.0-c68dc56-x86_64-linux-gnu
imbue <https://github.com/ImbueNetwork>
imbue testnet

The command-line arguments provided first will be passed to the parachain node, while the arguments
provided after -- will be passed to the relaychain node.

imbue-collator [parachain-args] -- [relaychain-args]

USAGE:
    imbue-collator [OPTIONS] [-- <RELAYCHAIN_ARGS>...]
    imbue-collator <SUBCOMMAND>

ARGS:
    <RELAYCHAIN_ARGS>...
            Relaychain arguments

OPTIONS:
        --alice
            Shortcut for `--name Alice --validator` with session keys for `Alice` added to keystore```
````

Comment: How did you create `pukimak.json`? Probably you need to update this to the latest version of Substrate.

Comment: Generated the chain spec using the imbue collator with this command:
```Used local chain spec via this command: ./target/debug/imbue-collator build-spec --chain imbue-dev --raw --disable-default-bootnode > pukimak.json```

Comment: You need to build the chain with the `--features=runtime-benchmarks` flag

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, I am trying what you suggested to better understand the chain spec dependency. 
```./target/debug/imbue-collator build-spec --chain imbue-dev --raw --disable-default-bootnode --features=runtime-benchmarks > pukimak.json```,
 it errors out with the following:
```error: Found argument '--features' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

 If you tried to supply `--features` as a value rather than a flag, use `-- --features`

USAGE:
    imbue-collator build-spec --chain <CHAIN_SPEC>

For more information try --help```

Comment: Features should be before build-spec

Comment: Tried as suggested but getting an exception as well
```./target/debug/imbue-collator --features runtime-benchmarks build-spec --chain imbue-dev --raw --disable-default-bootnode > pukimak.json
error: Found argument '--features' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

 If you tried to supply `--features` as a value rather than a flag, use `-- --features`

USAGE:
    imbue-collator [OPTIONS] [-- <RELAYCHAIN_ARGS>...]
    imbue-collator <SUBCOMMAND>

For more information try --help```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add your `proposal` pallet into [benchmark metadata](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/96d736ce75e8467862cd63037faa6d6e56122532/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1933) like this

Code change based on the input provided above:

````
    impl frame_benchmarking::Benchmark<Block> for Runtime {
        fn benchmark_metadata(extra: bool) -> (
            Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkList>,
            Vec<frame_support::traits::StorageInfo>,
        ) {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkList};
            use frame_support::traits::StorageInfoTrait;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            let mut list = Vec::<BenchmarkList>::new();
            list_benchmarks!(list, extra);

            let storage_info = AllPalletsWithSystem::storage_info();

            return (list, storage_info)
        }

        fn dispatch_benchmark(
            config: frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkConfig
        ) -> Result<Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkBatch>, sp_runtime::RuntimeString> {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkBatch, TrackedStorageKey};

            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {}
            impl baseline::Config for Runtime {}

            let whitelist: Vec<TrackedStorageKey> = vec![
                // Block Number
                hex_literal::hex!("XXX1").to_vec().into(),
                // Total Issuance
                hex_literal::hex!("XXX2").to_vec().into(),
                // Execution Phase
                hex_literal::hex!("XXX3").to_vec().into(),
                // Event Count
                hex_literal::hex!("XXX4").to_vec().into(),
                // System Events
                hex_literal::hex!("XXX5").to_vec().into(),
            ];

            let mut batches = Vec::<BenchmarkBatch>::new();
            let params = (&config, &whitelist);
            add_benchmarks!(params, batches);

            Ok(batches)
        }
    }```
````

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much !!!

Benchmark code reference: https://github.com/ImbueNetwork/imbue/commit/c25d9a2411217eae8f41114d20ee85c320a94423

File updated:
runtime/development/src/lib.rs

Comment: Consider copying the relevant code into the answer itself, otherwise when the link stops working the answer will not make any sense.

Comment: Answer updated, @DanielChmielewski. Thanks.